# passing arguments from tcl exec command to batch file

Tags: batch-file, tcl

I use devcon.exe to enable\disable USB devices.I have a PID and VID from USB device and want to use exec command with batch file to disable this device.

TCL script:

```
set str [exec "VID_$VID&PID_$PID"]
```

batch file:

```
devcon.exe disable %1
```

and I get an error becuase the argument I pass to cmd is only the first part of my string : VID_$VID. some how the & prevents me to pass the full argument. do you have any ideas n how to pass full argument with '&' to cmd?

Comment: well, you need to escape any `&` symbols by pre-pending them with a `^` symbol.

Comment: what I did you enable/disable usb devices with devcon.exe is to build a string in TCL without using "/" or "&".just "*".so i used: set str     "USB*VID_$VID*PID_$PID" and pass it to devcon with:     set output [exec C:/disable.bat "$str"] and it worked!!

Comment: great! im glad you figured it out.